# Subscribe to Meteor.users collection updates

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-publications

I use [react-komposer](https://github.com/kadirahq/react-komposer) and React in my app and at one point I change user's `profile` property of `Meteor.users` collection item that reflects current user. The problem here is that it doesn't reactively loopback in a call of `render`. Whatever I do to Meteor.users collection, even though I refer to `Meteor.user()` within `render` function, doesn't re-render the component. If I do

```
render() {
  console.log('rendered');

  /// ...
}
```

then I can only see "rendered" on the console twice: once the component has been initially rendered and the second time other subscriptions are ready.

I'd like to subscribe to `Meteor.users` collection but I don't know if there's a way to do.

I could definitely use Tracker to react to every Tracker loop but it feels too 1.2 to me. But is it the only way to do?

Also, I definitely have read other Q&As about `Meteor.users` like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198683/subscribing-to-meteor-users-collection) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34888053/meteor-users-collection) but the idea of wrapping users collection into pub/sub directly feels unnatural, and hardly is a good way to listen to every update in the collection.

Comment: There is nothing unnatural on publishing and subscribing to Meteor.users. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make a publication on the server code regarding the meteor.users collection.

```
    Meteor.publish('allUsers', function allUsers() {
      return Meteor.users.find({}, {
        fields: {
          services: 0,
        },
     });
   });
```

Then you can subscribe on your container to that publication and query Meteor.users collection and send that result to the component.

```
const composer = (props, onData) => {
const userHandle = Meteor.subscribe('allUsers');
if (userHandle.ready()) {
    const users = Meteor.users.find({}).fetch();
    onData(null, {
        users,
    });
}
};
export default composeWithTracker(composer)(YourComponent);
```

After this any change done to the collection inside YourComponent will be reflected client side.